# Use a static field defined in an enum as an argument in the constructor

Tags: java, constructor, enums

I have an enum and want to use a static value as the argument in the constructor.

```
public enum Enum
{
    e1(0),
    e2(1),
    e3(SPECIAL_VALUE);

    static int SPECIAL_VALUE = -1;

    int value;

    private Enum(int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

In this example, `SPECIAL_VALUE` is accessed before it is initialized, so this clearly doesn't work.  I was wondering if there was a common solution.  Or a reason why I shouldn't need to do this.

NOTE: There's probably a duplicate out there somewhere, but everything I can find has to do with using a static field in the body of the constructor, not as an argument, and I don't think the solutions presented there are applicable.

Comment: Reason: Cannot reference a field before it is defined.

Comment: Is there a problem with the use of `final`?

Comment: @Jashaszun `final` will not solve the issue.

Comment: @user3218114 Why not? Then it is a compile-time constant.

Comment: Why would you use a static field here when you can input the desired value directly ?

Comment: @Jashaszun Its defintiion is after its use, that doesn't work with any combination of modifiers.

Comment: @Jashazun So are the enums.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I would if I had a Java compiler near me.

Comment: @m4rtin because if this is possible you could load the value from a `static` method which may retrieve the real values from configuration like properties file or a database.

Comment: @Jashaszun http://ideone.com/

Comment: @Jashaszun http://ideone.com/ there's no excuse now :)

Comment: @HunterMcMillen and LuiggiMendoza Wow. I've never heard of that before. Will use way more often. :)

Comment: It looks like [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you explain what purpose would have passing value from static field in your real code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
package test;

public enum Enum
{

    e1(0),
    e2(1),
    e3(SPECIAL_VALUE());

    static int SPECIAL_VALUE(){return -1;}

    int value;

    private Enum(int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public int getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println(e3.name());
        System.out.println(e3.getValue());
    }
}
```

tried ideone for the first time, voila! http://ideone.com/Bz1N69

Comment: Ahhh so simple.  Plus it maintains the structure.  Thanks

Comment: @MarJohnson But be careful with this solution, because if you will want to rewrite `SPECIAL_VALUE()` method to actually return some static `SPECIAL_VALUE` it will return `0` or `null` instead of actual value (because it will not be initialized yet).

Comment: @Pshemo Good to remember.  But I can define the field SPECIAL_VALUE = SPECIAL_VALUE().

Answer (score 3):

You can declare a package-local class in the same file as `Enum` and declare the constant in it.  That will allow you to reference the constant in the `Enum` declaration.

```
public enum Enum
{
    e1(0),
    e2(1),
    e3(EnumConstants.SPECIAL_VALUE);

    int value;

    private Enum(int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

class EnumConstants
{
   static final int SPECIAL_VALUE = -1;
}
```

Comment: Another (better option IMO) would be to use a `static` method instead of a `static` constant. This way, you can process the value and make it a constant for the enum at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the reverse - initialize `e3` with a literal value, and expose the fact that it's special via a `public static` field:

```
public enum Enum
{
    e1(0),
    e2(1),
    e3(-1);

    public static int SPECIAL_VALUE = e3.value;

    int value;

    private Enum(int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, I really hate this design. It's all backwards.

Comment: @Sotirios: i don't see why, it makes as much sense as what the OP asked for. there's still a magic number in the Enum class either way.

Comment: @NathanHughes Don't get me wrong, I hate all these designs...I'd very much like to see the use case.

Answer (score 0):

Enums are themselves static final so you could do something like this:

```
public enum Enum {

   e1(0),
   e2(1),
   SPECIAL_VALUE(-1),
   //use the value reference
   e3(SPECIAL_VALUE.getValue());

   int value;

  private Enum(int value)
  {
    this.value = value;
  }

  public int getValue() {
    return value;
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Another way around would be moving initialization of `value` to *static initialization block* which would be placed after `SPECIAL_VALUE`.

```
public enum Enum {

    e1, e2, e3;

    static int SPECIAL_VALUE = -1;


    static {
        e1.value = 0;
        e2.value = 1;
        e3.value = SPECIAL_VALUE;
    }

    int value;
}
```